# pandas rolling_min and rolling_max different behavior?

Tags: python, pandas, max, min

I have a pandas data frame with three columns id,date,value.

```
Out[411]:
symbol  date_col    PX_HIGH
0   BF/B US Equity  2014-01-02  75.6800
1   DLTR US Equity  2014-01-02  56.5600
2   EMN US Equity   2014-01-02  80.5300
83620 rows × 3 columns
```

I would like to compute the rolling max and min on these values grouping by symbol. For rolling max

```
df.groupby('symbol')['PX_HIGH'].apply(lambda x: pd.rolling_max(x,window=20,min_periods=20)
```

And I get

```
Out[418]:
0    NaN
...
83605     54.5400
83606     56.0500
Length: 83620, dtype: float64
```

However, when I do the samething using rolling min

```
df.groupby('symbol')['PX_HIGH'].apply(lambda x: pd.rolling_min(x,window=20,min_periods=20)
```

I get

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-419-030ef09b7d35> in <module>()
  1 
  ----> 2 update_df.groupby('symbol')['PX_HIGH'].apply(lambda x: pd.rolling_min(x,20,20))
  ...

  ValueError: min_periods (20) must be <= window (17)
```

Any reason for why this might be? I'm using pandas 0.13.1

Comment: That does seem strange, not sure what is going on there, but you might want to update to latest stable pandas (14.1) and see if that solves it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why `pd.rolling_max()` worked while `pd.rolling_min()` didn't, but I think this issue was fixed in Pandas 0.15.0 -- see first item under http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0150-roll (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7766).

Comment: Thanks, will upgrade.